# Jenkins email ext jelly script include file contents

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jelly, email-ext

Can I display the contents of another file in my jelly script output?

Comment: So, have you solved your problem?

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert unfortunately I was busy with other stuff with this on hold, I'll update the description once I test it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is included in the workspace of the job, declare your variable such as:

```
<j:set var="fileContent" value="${build.getWorkspace().child("results.html")}"/>
```

And call it this way:

```
${fileContent}
```

Comment: This appears to get the file path rather then the contents when i use it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the ${FILE, path} token to include the contents of a file (path is relative to your workspace directory).

This info is taken from the Content Token Reference in the email-ext part of your job configuration.  Click the question mark on the right to get the full list of tokens.

Comment: Unfortunately that token cannot be used 'inside' a jelly script. I already have a custom jelly script, I'm looking for a way to populate parts of that custom template

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`util:loadText`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jelly/libs/util/tags.html#util%3aloadText) which is a "tag which loads text from a file or URI into a Jelly variable."

```
<u:loadText var="contents" file="${filename}"/>
${contents}
```

Haven't used it inside of Jenkins before... let us know if it works.

Comment: I did use as is above but it didn't work, so instead of using tag <u: use tag <util:, so the sentece will be:
<util:loadText var="contents" file="${filename}"/>
${contents}
And it works perfect !