# Jenkin email-ext: How do I include the contents of an html file in my jelly script output?

Tags: jenkins, email-ext, jelly, jenkins-email-ext

My Jenkins build produces a HTML file. I want to include this file in the HTML output of my jelly script via the Jenkins email-ext plugin.

I saw this answer in an old post but, as one person wrote, it only print the file path and not the content

> If the file is included in the workspace of the job, declare your variable such as:

```
<j:set var="fileContent" value="${build.getWorkspace().child("results.html")}"/>
```

> And call it this way:

```
${fileContent}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure how to link this to the other post I read. Here is the link (I hope): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371665/jenkins-email-ext-jelly-script-include-file-contents)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I found my own answer. This works for me:

```
<j:set var="fileContent" value="${build.getWorkspace().child('polyspace').child('ps_results_summary.html').readToString()}"/>
${fileContent}
```

Without the .readToString() method I only got the file path returned.

Comment: To use this in general, you'll need to add `<st:contentType value="text/html"/>` before. Otherwise, the end user will just get an octet stream.